# pg_wal getting full in Master DB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I also have a similar setup with master-slave (primary-standby) streaming replication set up on 2 physical nodes.The replication is working correctly and walsender and walreceiver both work fine.But in my case, the ***pg_wal in master is getting full and wal files are not being cleaned up***. My archive mode is disabled. Can anyone help?

Postgres Version 12. Running on RHEL-7.8

Here is my configuration in Master
[Master Runtime Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb8P2.png)

Here is my configuration in Streaming Replication [Streaming Replication Runtime Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RI17.png)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Very likely you have a stale replication slot.  Look at

```
SELECT slot_name, active, restart_lsn
FROM pg_replication_slots;
```

If you find an inactive one with an old `restart_lsn` you have found the problem. Use the `pg_drop_replication_slot` function to get rid of it, then `pg_wal` will slowly shrink back to `max_wal_size`.

You should also check if you have high values in `wal_keep_size` (`wal_keep_segments` in older releases). That will also make PostgreSQL retain old WAL segments.